# Могу ли я использовать Qt5 не открывая своих исходных кодов?

Tags: qt, qt5, лицензирование

Ведь LGPL подразумевает что я должен:

1. линковать динамически библиотеку

   (работаю под Linux и тут как раз проблемы с динамической линковкой).
   А также
2. я не имею права изменять код Qt без раскрытия кода изменений.

   (Так же хотел уточнить что будет считаться изменением библиотеки Qt (например перегрузка оператора и.т.д)).

Comment: можете. и если вы  перегрузите оператор вы код Qt не измените, а вот если вы полетите в исходники  Qt и там начнете править это будет считаться изменением.

Comment: А если я просто соберу статически, без изменения исходных кодов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать можете, модифицировать — нет. Что значит модифицировать? Значит изменять любой файл из пакета Qt, с последующей компиляцией модуля, его содержащего, и использование скомпилированного модуля в своём проекте. Как правило, это не нужно.

Что касается динамической компоновки: в Linux нет никаких проблем с этим, поэтому нет никакого смысла компоновать статически. Если Вас беспокоят зависимости — подтягивайте их при установке пакета.

Comment: @Cerbo, вроде в первом предложении всё написано по-русски.